# Drop down options in "Needs Answer" don't perform as expected

Tags: support, status-declined, new-nav

Here are the drop down options under "Needs Answer":

[image: Needs answer Drop Down]

This drop down is specific to "Needs Answer", not generic over all tabs.

Here are what I imagine they should do, if you keep all four of them:

- "**All**" - Should display all questions that do not have an accepted/upvoted answer *and* featured questions.
- "**Needs Answer**" - I'm not sure about this one. It seems to duplicate "All", not to mention duplicating the tab... it seems there's some interest in the option to exclude "No answer" questions, so maybe it shows only questions that have low-quality answers or answers that don't have upvotes.

[image: User who likes excluding no-answer questions]

- "**No Answer**" - This should show only questions that have zero answers.
- "**Bounties**" - This shows only questions with bounties.

So, here's the problem:

- "**All**" currently shows some larger subset of questions... even ones with accepted answers. I'm not sure what it's showing as it doesn't seem to be identical to the regular "all" view but it's certainly showing stuff that doesn't "need answers".

[image: All questions view]

- "Needs Answer" should probably have a different name. I don't know what but it seems silly for a subcategory to have the same name as the main category... **or** just get rid of it and limit the drop down to the three "All, "no answer", and "bounties".

Unless there's a strong interest in viewing **only** questions that have an answer but one that's not accepted/upvoted, I think it can just be removed in favor of the "all" option, which gets rid of the redundant terminology.

Comment: As to how the "all" option works here, see the answers to [this related question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/256947/162011).

Comment: @ChristianRau But that doesn't really address why questions with accepted answers appear under "all". :(

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "new nav" has been discontinued long ago.

Comment: While "[New navigation, alpha 2 released](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/259220/282094)" is no longer in effect, the tab:  https://meta.stackexchange.com/unanswered or psuedo-tag:   https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/unanswered-questions replace the old "need answer" tab.

Answer (score 1):

The "need answer" filter shows questions that have no upvoted or accepted answers. While these questions might have answers, they are possibly still in need of a new one.

The reason why this is included is to provide backwards-compatibility to the current `/unanswered` top level navigation.

Comment: I think however, that she doesn't really argue against the "need answer" option (at least not against its functionality) but rather against its naming and the relevance of the extended "all" option. What she actually seems to propose is a renaming of the "need answer" option (with its given functionality) into "all" (since it shows all questions that, well, need an answer), rather than a mere removal of the "unanswered" functionality.

Comment: Yes, @ChristianRau I'm trying to discern the difference between "All" and "needs answer" since all seems to duplicate it but with a few other questions (for example questions with accepted answers) that I'm not sure why they're there... particularly as one in my example is closed as a duplicate.

Comment: @Catija Since what you propose is [actually what happened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/261390/162011) in the new version, one might even argue that this question should be retagged `status-completed`.