# New navigation, alpha 2 released

Tags: discussion, new-nav

> Update: [A Release Candidate has been announced](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308875/new-navigation-release-candidate)

[image: cheese fountain]

Last month, we introduced a number of changes to the navigation for selected users:

- A new alpha-testing platform
- Unified question list with three tabs and a number of knobs to customize your question list selection
- New top nav

We received a [bunch of feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/?sort=newest&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=new-nav)—thanks! That was amazing!

After reviewing it, merging it with the internal impressions and some in-depth UX investigation by [our design meister, Kurtis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/278865/kurtis-beavers), we've developed a new version and we are ready for your <del>hate and blame</del> wonderful feedback and testing.

**Will you help?**

## How to participate

We have a number of willing <del>victims</del> candidates from the previous iteration, but we'll step it up a tad this time.

### Mark your user as a candidate

[image: the new "New Navigation" panel]

Go to your [user preferences page](/users/preferences/current), look at the bottom. Check the checkbox, or un-check it to go back to normal. Checking the box puts you in a waiting list.

### Wait

We activate users in tranches, randomly. There is no guarantee that we'll use all candidates straight away. Last time a lot of people were confused by this. Don't be :-)

### Report on meta

**Please don't report bugs and feature requests here**: use this question for general considerations only.

You can use separate questions tagged with [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) or [new-nav](/questions/tagged/new-nav) [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) as appropriate.

## What's new?

### Sticky preferences

Your last tab is saved, as well as your preferences within the tabs. In other words, clicking on the homepage logo sends you back to the last tab you were using, without any filters. Clicking on a tag sends you to the last tab you were using, filtered by that tag.

### Real-time notifications

Most tabs should have real-time notifications now, including the "need answers" pages, and pages filtered by tags (with "any" or "all")

### "Hot" questions can be filtered by tag

That was not possible before, now it is

### "Recommended" is now a tag filter

Rationale: although it doesn't, strictly speaking, filter by tags, it does show questions recommended for you and this is very heavily influenced by your tags (preferred or actively used). Moving it to a tag filter makes the navigation much more intuitive

### List permalink

There is now a permalink for sharing a question list at the bottom of the page

### Misc

- "Bounties" link, now says... "<n> bounties" instead of just "<n>"
- "Need answer" is now "need answers"
- Tab design is back to... tabs (on Stack Overflow)

---

**Previous announcements**

- [New navigation for Stack Overflow is in alpha testing](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/256814/new-navigation-for-stack-overflow-is-in-alpha-testing)
- [Let’s improve our site navigation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/251095/let-s-improve-our-site-navigation)

Comment: So that's why everything looked so new and fancy :)

Comment: While sticky preferences sounds gross, I'm super glad to see it implemented :D

Comment: I hope I actually get to test it this time around...

Comment: This question clogged muh arteries

Comment: @TinyGiant I tested it and I honestly loved it! It's so much better than the old navigation! This really improved the usability.

Comment: I OPTED IN THREE SECONDS AGO AND IT'S NOT WORKING, WHY? Just kidding, I'll be patient.

Comment: What is the determinant for 'new'?

Comment: Real-time notifications = still not working: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297627/no-real-time-update-from-new-nav

Comment: I still dont get why the page does so many postbacks or refreshes on clicking the various views.  Why cant you guys use more ajax?

Comment: @JonH ajax is planned, but not implemented quite yet.

Comment: I dont get why you guys publish this stuff into production half assed?   Sorry for the language but shouldn't all of this be done and then published?  Im not saying the fully final product but as an example, this specific case, I would want the ajax in there before I rolled it out to something as large as stackoverflow!  I guess the opt in "option" solves that, shoot me now.

Comment: Sticky filters would be nice.

Comment: @Frank see my edit in my comment, then you can laugh at me!

Comment: Really enjoying this iteration.

Comment: @JonH you are the first user who mentioned AJAX (as far as I remember), besides our internal conversations. Evidently people don't feel that AJAX is as urgent as other stuff we rolled out. As David pointed out, it's happening, but it was better to test other stuff first.

Comment: I don't think the post back versus AJAX issue is really much of an issue. You would still have to wait for the server to give the response, the page has no images or anything, so the pages tend to load in like 400ms or less depending on script and style caching. Posting back is almost preferred here because it allows for two important things. Very direct feedback on the time it is taking to load, and posting back allows for a unique url to be used to return to the current selection.

Comment: @Sklivvz - its because I rock...just like your internal people who conversed with you about ajax - they too rock, let them know i said so.

Comment: @JonH - Are you addressing ajaxing the content in when switching tabs, or when the new question option would show when sorted on newest in a custom tag?

Comment: @TravisJ - first option you mentioned, as well as some of the filtering.

Comment: Wait, if I'm still enrolled to get the last one (I checked, the checkbox is still checked) do I have to uncheck then recheck the checkbox?

Comment: @TinyGiant you are still entitled but we enroll people at random. I will enroll 1k more users as soon as the first batch of bugs is fixed (1-2 days)

Comment: Thanks. Here's hoping :)

Comment: Does this have anything at all to do with the new image uploader?

Comment: @uɐɯsOuɐɥʇɐN nope, they are completely different things

Comment: Does anybody have a link (MSO?) which talk about why tabs are back? I'm curious about it.

Comment: *"clicking on the homepage logo sends you back to the last tab you were using, **without any filters**"* Why without filters? without it also saving filters i'm still going to end up using a bookmark rather than the logo.

Comment: When does the responsive design update come? 6-8 years? It should have been done 6-8 years *ago*…

Comment: @bjb568 you mean the mobile version? It's on the roadmap, but after this is reasonably done.

Comment: Responsive design is the *absence* of a mobile version, i.e. it works for all devices without a min or max width. It needs to bring all the desktop features to mobile, but also work properly on screens larger than 1024px across. (hint: get rid of table layout!)

Comment: @bjb568 I don't understand why it should be clumped with this project

Comment: Well, it's not. I've just been waiting for it for years and it never seems to happen. I've already posted multiple times on meta about it.

Comment: @bjb568 it's not a philosophical stance. It's just very complex. The first step is fixing our CSS stylesheets, and that's being rolled out gradually.

Comment: I'm more of the "trash the entire front end and rebuild" mentality, but incremental improvements work too :)

Comment: @bjb568 we need to support all the sites at the same time, so right now we'd need to change hundreds of CSS together with the code. We're simply doing the CSS first.

Comment: I feel like waiting in line for the next gen product of *insert your favorite brand here*.

Comment: Adding 1000 more users now. Good luck!

Comment: Just got added, thanks. Looking and feeling great. Love the fact that it also remembers if I want newest or recently active to show on a per-tag basis (that is, when viewing tags in general). Because it used a query string to sort by newest, I was worried (at first) that it wouldn't remember the setting. But it did, so that's great. Fantastic work on the new nav - really do like it. :-)

Comment: Why doesn't the link work for me? It gives me a 404.

Comment: _"Last time a lot of people were confused by this. Don't be :-)"_ Haha this is an awesome way to fix a confusing system :P

Comment: Also if Sklivvz is not looking for feedback (he's gone on _every_ answer here asking its author to delete it) then why is this a Meta post? There is even a closure reason on Meta for "does not invite feedback" or whatever. I get that you want individual bug reports in individual questions, but then what is this page for, beyond the announcement? Do it on the blog instead? Just a thought x

Comment: I am inviting feeback. Not bug reports or feature requests as answers (we welcome them as separate posts, of course!). There are other kinds of feedback (e.g. requests for clarifications, general comments...)

Comment: disliked it, opted out again, too used to old navigation and too much clicking around to get to hot questions

Comment: Hey, the live updates don't work at all.

Comment: I don't like the sticky preferences. I used to use the logo for the recently active questions, and the questions button for the new questions. It's too hard for me to open the drop down menu and select recently active or new, since I like using the full site on my phone. I usually end up fat fingering and give up.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yes, very strange indeed. After taking all the time to get acquainted with this post, and all 44 comments as well, there are *no* answers for the community to examine and vote on. Instead we would have to hunt for them in the questions list by searching by the new tag [tag:new-nav]? This makes no sense to me and is bucking convention very strongly. The response "answers can't be marked as duplicate" is a completely bogus reason. Duplicate answers in these scenarios are rather uncommon and are fairly obvious. This is the place for the community to discuss issues.

Comment: 5 deleted answers, 5 comments very brazenly requesting they are removed. That doesn't seem to seek community input to me.

Comment: @TravisJ Can you explain better what you are trying to say? Bug reports and feature requests are always reported as questions for all stack exchange features. If you want to give other forms of feedback about this current iteration, whether you like it, or don't, and why: you are welcome to do so here. The answers which i kindly (and not brazenly) asked to remove were 4 bug reports (all already fixed, including a duplicate) and a single 2 line comment that fit much better in the discussion already happening elsewhere.

Comment: I really like the `favorite` tagFilter, but it reverts to `all tags` every time I return to the question list. That's an RSI inducing number of clicks to get back to it... can't it be sticky?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because all reports should come as new questions, as OP clearly said to all now deleted 5 (!) answers. Let's not waste people's time.

Comment: @TravisJ true, voted to close. No idea why no diamond user hasn't simply closed it to avoid wasting users' time.

Comment: @Sklivvz you mean feedback like "I love it!" or "I hate it!", and that doesn't fit as answer to begin with. Any real feedback will always ask for something. So really no point leaving this open.

Comment: @Sklivvz Typically, such feedback-asking posts allow to provide bugs and feature-requests in answers. Why? First reason - you get notified immediately and get a nice collection of bugs and requests there. Second reason - as the question stays featured, all the bugs and requests (more importantly the latter ones) get *more* input by community which arrives to this question through community bulletin.

Comment: So what we have is not just a model being ill-used for meta (SO model does _not_ work here!!) but also a model being _so_ ill-used that even the moderators can't do it properly. Wow!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit well, it's reopened now. Let's see how many will post bugs here, just to have it removed shortly after.

Comment: Can you describe what features a good answer (as in, one that should not be deleted) would be?  Should feedback on the alpha system itself go here as an answer, or somewhere else?  Aside, the [feedback link above](http://meta.stackexchange.com/?sort=newest&layout=expanded&tagFilter=list&tags=new-nav) doesn't actually seem to show [tag:new-nav] tagged meta posts only.

Comment: Did you take away the old new navigation here on MSE?  I'm not seeing either the recent new nav or what you link to on SO now.  My preferences still show me as opted in.

Comment: @MonicaCellio yeah, for now the new version doesn't work with this CSS