# In Featured tabs, why does the page title use “Bounty” when a tag is selected, but "Featured" without a tag selected?

Tags: discussion, bug, question-lists, navigation

Without a tag selected, the (main) Featured tab uses "Featured" in the page title, however with a tag selected the page title uses "Bounty" instead.

*For example:*

The page title for the main **Featured** tab on *any* Stack Exchange site is:

> Featured Questions - <Site Name>

e.g.

> Featured Questions - Stack Overflow

However, when a tag is selected, the page title becomes:

> Bounty '<Tag Name>' Questions - <Site Name>

e.g.

> Bounty 'java' Questions - Stack Overflow

Why is there a discrepancy (*Bounty* vs *Featured*) in page titles? Is it a bug or intended?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm sure it is a bug, though the navigation you're talking about is slowly becoming obsolete because [there's a new navigation being tested currently](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259220/new-navigation-alpha-2-released), and it's already in the second alpha.

This new navigation doesn't have this bug: when you select all the bountied questions, it says:

> Questions that need answers

And when you select specific tag(s), the tag name is just prepended to the title:

> 'javascript' questions that need answers

Answer (score 2):

It does seem like this should be consistent.

I think "Featured Questions" sounds better than "Bounty Questions", especially for the "main" Featured tab itself when there is no tag selected.
"Bounty" is a thing itself, whereas "Featured" is the name for the tab/area you are in.

So the page title for a Featured tab when a tag is selected could also use "Featured", eg:

> Featured 'java' Questions - Stack Overflow